# Can Kafka producer do consumer lag aware partitioning

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We a Kafka producer produces messages to a topic that is consumed by only one group of consumers. The speed of consumers is quite different. We always have a certain amount of consumer lags as a buffer.

Is it possible for the producer to know the lag of each partition of the consumer group and produce messages to the partition with the lowest lag first? And is it possible if I use C/C++ clients or Java clients?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, given that you can lookup any consumer group name's lag from within the producer, however as the consumers are running those values will fluctuate and you're coupling yourself to knowing which consumers are running, which would be an anti-pattern in Kafka.

I'd suggest tweaking other consumer settings like poll sizes / frequency

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, I am looking for a kind of way to let the consumer consume any pending messages, not restricted to its assigned partitions. I found the Kafka REST Proxy which seems to serve this purpose. However, the performance of consuming via http is much worse than the native client. And I'm not sure if it's the typical use case of the Proxy.

Comment: The REST Proxy just wraps the normal native Java consumer. I don't imagine it would solve any issues you're experiencing.

Comment: If I create one consumer instance on the Proxy, then this proxy consumer listens to all the partitions. If I let all my consumer clients call the fetch data API on this instance, it looks like the clients can consume from any partition. Am I right?

Comment: The proxy manages multiple consumer instance threads on its own. You just use the API to create a consumer group, then pull the topic from one endpoint. Which will not scale to multiple instances of your own app

Comment: So it is not possible to use the API to pull the same proxy consumer instance from different app instances, right? Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, the REST Proxy is really only meant to be used where you are unable to write a native consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible.

You must ensure that the policy you use distributes the work to all partitions equally.
You can provide a **custom partitioner** that suits your needs.

Look for example: https://dzone.com/articles/custom-partitioner-in-kafka-lets-take-quick-tour.

Default partitioner strategy is round robin